# Recycler View inside frame layout not scrolling vertically

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view inside fragment **"Home"** and it is not scrolling vertically. Can someone please help me out !!
My fragment is inside home screen containing a toolbar, drawer navigation and bottom tab navigation . i got another recycler view inside home fragment and that recycler view is not scrolling

This recyclerView is not scrolling >>>

Here is my HomeScreen code

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".homeSc"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerNavigationDrawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/drawerNavigationToolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="#B3E3E1"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:titleTextColor="@color/black"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/drawerNavigationFragmentContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:isScrollContainer="true"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/drawerNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_nav_header"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />
    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Here is my Home Fragment Code**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayoutHomeSc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerVFragHomeSc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**Recycler View Adapter Code**

```
    package com.example.knowledgespaceapk;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class adapterRecVHomeFrag  extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<adapterRecVHomeFrag.myviewholder>{

    ArrayList<dataModelRecVFragHome> dataHolder;

    public adapterRecVHomeFrag(ArrayList<dataModelRecVFragHome> dataHolder) {
        this.dataHolder = dataHolder;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public myviewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new myviewholder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_row_design_rec_homef
                                    ,parent,false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myviewholder holder, int position) {
        holder.img.setImageResource(dataHolder.get(position).getImage());
        holder.title.setText(dataHolder.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.desc.setText(dataHolder.get(position).getDescription());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataHolder.size();
    }

    class myviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView img;
        TextView title,desc;

        public myviewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageVSingleRowDesRecHomeF);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleTxtVSingleRDesRecHomeF);
            desc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.descriptionTxtVSingleRDesRecHomeF);
        }
    }
}
```

**Recyler View Element layout Code**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageVSingleRowDesRecHomeF"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="219dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/fest" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleTxtVSingleRDesRecHomeF"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/descriptionTxtVSingleRDesRecHomeF"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**Home Screen Java Code**

```
    package com.example.knowledgespaceapk;


import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.os.Bundle;


import com.example.knowledgespaceapk.databinding.ActivityHomeScBinding;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;


public class homeSc extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_sc);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.drawerNavigationToolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerNavigationDrawerLayout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,
                            toolbar,R.string.open,R.string.close);
       drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();


        replaceFrag(new HomeFragment());
        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(item -> {

            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.home : replaceFrag(new HomeFragment()); break;
                case R.id.group: replaceFrag(new GroupFragment()); break;
                case R.id.notification:replaceFrag(new NotificationFragment()); break;
            }
            return true;
        });

    }//End OnCreate

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    private  void replaceFrag(Fragment fragment){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout,fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}//End Main
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the `DrawerLayout` as parent view in your HomeScreen XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerNavigationDrawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".homeSc"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomNavigationView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/drawerNavigationToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#B3E3E1"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/black"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawerNavigationFragmentContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"/>
        
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/drawerNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />
    
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you for your help. Your solution worked really well. Problem solved cheers! But may you please help me understand what's the logic behind putting the drawer layout on top as the parent container for all the elements? How does this solve my problem?

Comment: The `DrawerLayout` must be the parent element of the layout. The fact that you were placing it at the same level as the `FrameLayout` containing the `RecyclerView` might have prevented this layout to be able to receive the gestures because captured by the `DrawerLayout`.